# How to use CSS to change text?

Tags: html, css, content-management-system

We are using a CMS and we have access to the CSS. How would we change the text `About Us`?

See code below.

```
<div class="row footer-columns">
     <div class="col-md-3">
         <div class="footer-col-title">
             <h4>About Us</h4>
         </div>
        <div class="footermodule custom-html">
             Shapco is a nationally-recognized, award-winning printer, <span class="st">providing premium quality printing for graphic designers and creative professionals.</span><br/>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="footer-col-title">
           <h4>Contact Us</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="contactblcok custom-html">
           <h5>Technical Support </h5>
           <p><a href="mailto:marcomportal@shapco.com">marcomportal@shapco.com<br /></a></p>
          <p>Main: 612.375.1150 • Toll: 800.230.2828 </p><p>Hours: M- F 7:00 AM to 6:00 PM Central </p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: The code you have provided does not contain "About Us"

Comment: Looks like the question was edited to display the HTML code. Now `<h4>About Us</h4>` is in there.

Comment: It is right at the top 4th line down <h4>About Us</h4>

Answer (score 2):

Can't find a code with your text. You can't change a text with a css only, but some hack exists:

```
.element {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.element:before {
  content: "Your new text here...";
  visibility: visible;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fy4m8ubh/

Comment: This works if it is one element, but this has multiple columns and I only want to change the one column heading

Comment: you can't do it only with css